# Spring Boot Tomcat 8, Parse Fatal Error at line 46 column 2: The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, spring-boot

I have a spring boot web app, tomcat 8, java 8, Mysql 5.7. I have encrypted connections to tomcat using the following guide https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-encrypt-tomcat-8-connections-with-apache-or-nginx-on-centos-7

My tomcat/conf/server.xml file has been edited exactly according to the post. I can successfully access the tomcat homepage. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

My POM.xml looks as follows

```html
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
 <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
 <groupId>com.app.name</groupId>
 <artifactId>appname</artifactId>
 <packaging>war</packaging>
 <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
 <name>Name Of Webapp</name>
 
  <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <start-class>com.app.name.Application</start-class>
        <jackson.version>2.3.2</jackson.version>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    
    <parent>
     <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
     <version>1.3.6.RELEASE</version>
 </parent>
    
 <dependencies>
  <!-- Spring boot -->
        <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
     </dependency>
     <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
     </dependency>
     <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
         <scope>provided</scope>
     </dependency>
     <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
         <scope>test</scope>
     </dependency>
     <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
     </dependency>
         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
         </dependency>
         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
         </dependency>

         <dependency>
             <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
             <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
         </dependency>

         <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>16.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-guava</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>

  <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json -->
  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.json</groupId>
      <artifactId>json</artifactId>
      <version>20160810</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
   <groupId>mysql</groupId>
   <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
   <version>5.1.9</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
   <groupId>commons-httpclient</groupId>
   <artifactId>commons-httpclient</artifactId>
   <version>3.1</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
   <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
   <version>1.1.1</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>commons-pool</groupId>
   <artifactId>commons-pool</artifactId>
   <version>1.5.4</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
   <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
   <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
   <version>1.1.3</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
   <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
   <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
   <version>2.4</version>
  </dependency>
  <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-lang3 -->
  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
      <version>3.4</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
     <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
     <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
     <version>1.3.1</version> <!-- makesure correct version here -->
  </dependency>
  
  <dependency>
   <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
   <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
   <version>1.4</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
   <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
   <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
   <version>1.4</version>
  </dependency>
  
  <dependency>
            <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
            <artifactId>liquibase-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.2</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.pdfbox/pdfbox -->
  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
      <artifactId>pdfbox</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.0</version>
  </dependency>
  
  <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi-scratchpad -->
  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
      <artifactId>poi-scratchpad</artifactId>
      <version>3.9</version>
  </dependency>
  
  <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi-ooxml -->
  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
      <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
      <version>3.9</version>
  </dependency>
 </dependencies>
</project>
```

This is the error I get in catalina.out when starting up:

> 04-Apr-2017 23:25:40.648 INFO [Thread-5] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.pause Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-127.0.0.1-8080"]
>   04-Apr-2017 23:25:40.706 INFO [Thread-5] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.pause Pausing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-127.0.0.1-8009"]
>   04-Apr-2017 23:25:40.757 INFO [Thread-5] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.stopInternal Stopping service Catalina
>   04-Apr-2017 23:25:40.839 INFO [Thread-5] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.stop Stopping ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-127.0.0.1-8080"]
>   04-Apr-2017 23:25:40.851 INFO [Thread-5] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.stop Stopping ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-127.0.0.1-8009"]
>   04-Apr-2017 23:25:40.856 INFO [Thread-5] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.destroy Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-127.0.0.1-8080"]
>   04-Apr-2017 23:25:40.858 INFO [Thread-5] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.destroy Destroying ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-127.0.0.1-8009"]
>   04-Apr-2017 23:25:41.675 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version:        Apache Tomcat/8.5.13
>   04-Apr-2017 23:25:41.678 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server built:          Mar 27 2017 14:25:04 UTC
>   04-Apr-2017 23:25:41.678 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server number:         8.5.13.0
>   04-Apr-2017 23:25:41.679 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Name:               Linux
>   04-Apr-2017 23:25:41.679 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Version:            3.10.0-514.6.1.el7.x86_64
>   04-Apr-2017 23:25:41.679 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Architecture:          amd64
>   04-Apr-2017 23:25:41.679 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Java Home:             /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_60/jre
>   04-Apr-2017 23:25:41.679 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Version:           1.8.0_60-b27
>   04-Apr-2017 23:25:41.679 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
>   04-Apr-2017 23:25:41.679 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_BASE:         /opt/tomcat
>   04-Apr-2017 23:25:41.679 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_HOME:         /opt/tomcat
>   04-Apr-2017 23:25:41.680 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/opt/tomcat/conf/logging.properties
>   04-Apr-2017 23:25:41.680 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
>   04-Apr-2017 23:25:41.680 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.awt.headless=true
>   04-Apr-2017 23:25:41.680 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom
>   04-Apr-2017 23:25:41.680 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048
>   04-Apr-2017 23:25:41.680 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=org.apache.catalina.webresources
>   04-Apr-2017 23:25:41.681 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Xms512M
>   04-Apr-2017 23:25:41.681 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Xmx1024M
>   04-Apr-2017 23:25:41.681 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -XX:+UseParallelGC
>   04-Apr-2017 23:25:41.681 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=/opt/tomcat
>   04-Apr-2017 23:25:41.684 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=/opt/tomcat
>   04-Apr-2017 23:25:41.684 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=/opt/tomcat/temp
>   04-Apr-2017 23:25:41.684 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: /usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib
>   04-Apr-2017 23:25:41.842 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
>   04-Apr-2017 23:25:41.870 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
>   04-Apr-2017 23:25:41.876 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
>   04-Apr-2017 23:25:41.877 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
>   04-Apr-2017 23:25:41.881 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Initialization processed in 744 ms
>   04-Apr-2017 23:25:41.935 SEVERE [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.fatalError Parse Fatal Error at line 46 column 2: The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed.
>    org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 46; columnNumber: 2; The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed.
>           at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:203)
>           at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.fatalError(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:177)
>           at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:441)
>           at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:368)
>           at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLScanner.reportFatalError(XMLScanner.java:1437)
>           at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$TrailingMiscDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:1397)
>           at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:606)
>           at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:510)
>           at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:848)
>           at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:777)
>           at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
>           at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1213)
>           at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:649)
>           at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.parse(Digester.java:1477)
>           at org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabase.open(MemoryUserDatabase.java:416)
>           at org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory.getObjectInstance(MemoryUserDatabaseFactory.java:102)
>           at org.apache.naming.factory.FactoryBase.getObjectInstance(FactoryBase.java:94)
>           at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getObjectInstance(NamingManager.java:321)
>           at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:839)
>           at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:159)
>           at org.apache.naming.NamingContextBindingsEnumeration.nextElementInternal(NamingContextBindingsEnumeration.java:117)
>           at org.apache.naming.NamingContextBindingsEnumeration.next(NamingContextBindingsEnumeration.java:71)
>           at org.apache.naming.NamingContextBindingsEnumeration.next(NamingContextBindingsEnumeration.java:34)

My server.xml file looks as follows:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
 Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
  contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
  this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
  The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
  (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
  the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

  Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
  distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
  WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
  See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
  limitations under the License.
-->
<!-- Note:  A "Server" is not itself a "Container", so you may not
     define subcomponents such as "Valves" at this level.
     Documentation at /docs/config/server.html
 -->
<Server port="8005" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener" />
  <!-- Security listener. Documentation at /docs/config/listeners.html
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityListener" />
  -->
  <!--APR library loader. Documentation at /docs/apr.html -->
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener" SSLEngine="on" />
  <!-- Prevent memory leaks due to use of particular java/javax APIs-->
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.ThreadLocalLeakPreventionListener" />

  <!-- Global JNDI resources
       Documentation at /docs/jndi-resources-howto.html
  -->
  <GlobalNamingResources>
    <!-- Editable user database that can also be used by
         UserDatabaseRealm to authenticate users
    -->
     <Resource name="UserDatabase" auth="Container"
              type="org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase"
              description="User database that can be updated and saved"
              factory="org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory"
              pathname="conf/tomcat-users.xml" />
  </GlobalNamingResources>
<!-- A "Service" is a collection of one or more "Connectors" that share
       a single "Container" Note:  A "Service" is not itself a "Container",
       so you may not define subcomponents such as "Valves" at this level.
       Documentation at /docs/config/service.html
   -->
  <Service name="Catalina">

    <!--The connectors can use a shared executor, you can define one or more named thread pools-->
    <!--
    <Executor name="tomcatThreadPool" namePrefix="catalina-exec-"
        maxThreads="150" minSpareThreads="4"/>
    -->


    <!-- A "Connector" represents an endpoint by which requests are received
         and responses are returned. Documentation at :
         Java HTTP Connector: /docs/config/http.html
         Java AJP  Connector: /docs/config/ajp.html
         APR (HTTP/AJP) Connector: /docs/apr.html
         Define a non-SSL/TLS HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8080
    -->
    <Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               address="127.0.0.1"
               redirectPort="8443" />
    <!-- A "Connector" using the shared thread pool-->
    <!--
    <Connector executor="tomcatThreadPool"
               port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443" />
    -->
    <!-- Define a SSL/TLS HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8443
         This connector uses the NIO implementation. The default
         SSLImplementation will depend on the presence of the APR/native
         library and the useOpenSSL attribute of the
         AprLifecycleListener.
         Either JSSE or OpenSSL style configuration may be used regardless of
         the SSLImplementation selected. JSSE style configuration is used below.
    -->
  <!--
    <Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
               maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true">
        <SSLHostConfig>
            <Certificate certificateKeystoreFile="conf/localhost-rsa.jks"
                         type="RSA" />
        </SSLHostConfig>
    </Connector>
    -->
    <!-- Define a SSL/TLS HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8443 with HTTP/2
         This connector uses the APR/native implementation which always uses
         OpenSSL for TLS.
         Either JSSE or OpenSSL style configuration may be used. OpenSSL style
         configuration is used below.
    -->
    <!--
    <Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol"
               maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true" >
        <UpgradeProtocol className="org.apache.coyote.http2.Http2Protocol" />
        <SSLHostConfig>
            <Certificate certificateKeyFile="conf/localhost-rsa-key.pem"
                         certificateFile="conf/localhost-rsa-cert.pem"
                         certificateChainFile="conf/localhost-rsa-chain.pem"
                         type="RSA" />
        </SSLHostConfig>
    </Connector>
    -->

    <!-- Define an AJP 1.3 Connector on port 8009 -->
    <Connector port="8009" address="127.0.0.1" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" />


    <!-- An Engine represents the entry point (within Catalina) that processes
         every request.  The Engine implementation for Tomcat stand alone
         analyzes the HTTP headers included with the request, and passes them
         on to the appropriate Host (virtual host).
         Documentation at /docs/config/engine.html -->

    <!-- You should set jvmRoute to support load-balancing via AJP ie :
    <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost" jvmRoute="jvm1">
    -->
    <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">
  <!--For clustering, please take a look at documentation at:
           /docs/cluster-howto.html  (simple how to)
           /docs/config/cluster.html (reference documentation) -->
       <!--
       <Cluster className="org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.SimpleTcpCluster"/>
       -->

       <!-- Use the LockOutRealm to prevent attempts to guess user passwords
            via a brute-force attack -->
       <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm">
         <!-- This Realm uses the UserDatabase configured in the global JNDI
              resources under the key "UserDatabase".  Any edits
              that are performed against this UserDatabase are immediately
              available for use by the Realm.  -->
         <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm"
                resourceName="UserDatabase"/>
       </Realm>

       <Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
             unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">

         <!-- SingleSignOn valve, share authentication between web applications
              Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html -->
         <!--
         <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.authenticator.SingleSignOn" />
         -->

         <!-- Access log processes all example.
              Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html
              Note: The pattern used is equivalent to using pattern="common" -->
         <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
                prefix="localhost_access_log" suffix=".txt"
                pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />
         <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve"
                 allow="something\.something\.something\.something|something\.something\.something\.something|something\.something\.something\.something" />
       </Host>
     </Engine>
   </Service>
 </Server>
```

Comment: @TilmanHausherr The only other one is server.xml and I have just posted it in an edit.

Comment: Please validate your XML file directly: http://www.xmlvalidation.com/index.php?id=1&L=0  I tried it but did not find any problem. But maybe there was some invisible char that isn't in the question.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr I validated server.xml and pom.xml, neither had any errors

Comment: Post your `conf/tomcat-users.xml`. Maybe the error is there

Comment: @Sigrist that file was not touched at all

Comment: It's not clear which XML has the problem. Looks like is not you pom.xml neither the server.xml. If you can start using eclipse or any IDE, add an exception breakpoint for `SAXParseException` and try to find out which XML is breaking